# Textbox value not showinge when sheet with the range containing the value is inactive

Tags: excel, vba

I have a textbox whose value should come from a cell in a range in sheet2, based on a combobox selection. The textbox value seems to appear only when sheet2 is the active sheet and doesn't work when some other sheet on the same workbook is active. My code below. I'll appreciate any help I can get.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim pump As String
    Dim searchTerm As Range
    pump = ComboBox1.Value
    Set searchTerm = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1:B999").Find(what:=pump, after:=Range("B1"), searchorder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
    TextBox2.Value = Cells(searchTerm.Row, 8)
End Sub
```

Comment: You should fully qualify the range assignment to TextBox2, e.g. at least via `TextBox2.Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(searchTerm.Row, 8)` or better via `TextBox2.Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(searchTerm.Row, 8)`, otherwise this code line is always referring to the active worksheet (possibly in another workbook, too) and doesn't find the wanted cell value.

Comment: You should also check if it's really not found: `If Not searchTerm Is Nothing Then _ TextBox2.Value = "" _ Else _ TextBox2.Value = searchTerm.Offset(,6).Value _ End If`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did fully qualify the range assignment to textbox2 and it worked perfectly. Am gratefull